# Some trouble with C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, user-interface, vcl, c++builder-6

I just tried write small program in C++ Builder 6(don't ask me why, its just a homework in institute).
So, my program must hide button1 when i resizing form.
But resize event raises after window created, its mean that after i start program button1 is already invisible.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
{
  Button1->Visible = false;
}
```

I tried use different resize events, but it don't works too.
What I'm doing wrong?

PS. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: In your tool for creating the forms, verify the default value of the button.  You may want to set it to disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.  The Form really does resize while it is being created, that is why you get the event.  There are many ways you can address this:

1. use a variable to ignore the first `OnResize` event until the form is ready:

   ```
   private:
       bool fReady;
   ```

   ```
   void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
   {
       if (!fReady)
           fReady = true;
       else
           Button1->Visible = false;
   }
   ```
2. use the Form's `OnShow` event to post a custom message to signal the form is ready:

   ```
   private:
       bool fReady;
   protected:
       virtual void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message);
   ```

   ```
   const UINT WM_READY = WM_APP + 100;

   void __fastcall TForm1::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
   {
       if (Message.Msg == WM_READY)
           fReady = true;
       else
           TForm::WndProc(Message);
   }

   void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
   {
       PostMessage(Handle, WM_READY, 0, 0);
   }

   void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
   {
       if (fReady)
           Button1->Visible = false;
   }
   ```
3. use a short timer instead of a custom message:

   ```
   private:
       bool fReady;
   ```

   ```
   void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TMessage &Message)
   {
       Timer1->Enabled = false;
       fReady = true;
   }

   void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
   {
       Timer1->Enabled = true;
   }

   void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
   {
       if (fReady)
           Button1->Visible = false;
   }
   ```

Just to name a few.

Comment: Why do you push the message instead of just setting `fReady = true;` in the `FormShow` handler?  (NB. `fReady` needs to be initialized to `false` in the constructor).

Comment: The OnShow event is triggered before the Form actually becomes visible onscreen, so the message post is just an added delay to make sure the user sees the window before allowing the button to hide. And the variable is initialized to false by the RTL by virtue of the fact that it is a member of the Form class and all `TObject` descendants (which `TForm1` is) automatically fill their allocated memory with zeros before the constructor is called.

Comment: Is that zero-memory behaviour something we should rely on when coding?

Comment: It is a feature specific to the Delphi/C++Builder compilers for the `TObject` class.  All `TObject`-derived classes are auto-initialized with zeros before the constructor is executed.  This is not standard C++ behavior, but it is reliable in C++Builder for `TObject`-derived classes only.